# is there some way to enable cross-site javascript, either in browser or in browser embedded within java application

Tags: java, browser, same-origin-policy

I am creating an application in which there will be multiple iframes within the main window- forms will be  opened for submission in the main window and each form's target iframe will be one of the many iframes available...

I want to be able to access the response of each form submission, i.e. I want to access content in child iframe from code in the main window.

Please clarify the following for me-

(1) As I understand Same Origin Policy does not permit the above scenario? Am I correct?
(2) Is there some way to enable the access to child iframe, that i require, in any web browser? I saw some posts on SO about this, and even tried some of the solutions, but nothing works (I tried Google Chrome, Firefox 6, Firefox 3.6 and Safari).
(3) In case its not possible to get such data access in browser, then can I get such access by embedding a browser component in my java desktop app? In such case which browser component do you recommend?

Comment: Normally, if you're doing a desktop app, you'd use Swing, at which point this is rather moot...  What are you trying to use iframes for, anyways?

Comment: i am redirecting the output of a form submission to an iframe- after submission i want to be able to access the contents of the iframe to see if the submission was successful...

Answer (score 1):

1. Only if the content of the child iframes is loaded from another domain.
2. Generally not. In some newer browsers, the target domain can use HTTP Access Control headers to allow cross-site requests to be made **to** it, but there is no way for the source site to make that decision.
3. I'm not familiar with Java browser components, so I'll let someone else answer this part.